# TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have a config file throwing error when only building with AOT `ionic cordova build android --prod`

> Error: ./src/config/.env.ts Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'content' of undefined at Object.optimizationLoader
>   (/Users/yasir/myApp/mobile/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/webpack/optimization-loader-impl.js:14:24)
>   at Object.loader
>   (/Users/yasir/myApp/mobile/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/webpack/optimization-loader.js:5:32)
>   @ ./src/providers/post-service.js 15:0-40 @
>   ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js @ ./src/app/main.ts

This is the content of the `.env.ts` file. The file is inside src `.src/config/.env.ts`

```
export const config: any = {
   serverUrl: "http://0.0.0.0:3000"
};
```

Comment: Can you show the code of this provider `post-service.ts`?

Comment: thank you for pointing that out... I commented out the import to config file in that service... but it continues to throw the same error to the next service provider where the `.env` file is imported...and its imported in all the services obviously.. the following is the simplest format of how I am using the `.env` file:
`import { config } from '../config/.env';`
`export class PostService { serverUrl = config.serverUrl; }

Comment: Had the same problem and it was related to a mispelling of a file in an import for me(was Uppercase instead of lowercase)

Comment: I'm not really sure, I keep checking , things seem to be ok, since I can `serve` and build without AOT... perhaps the way I am exporting `config` as shown above... or if you suggest other ways to achieve the same purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that on production build, its skipped files containing `dot` `.env`.. so I removed the dot `env` and everything got back to normal