# Cannot read property 'content' of undefined Angular

Tags: angular

I am doing a normal http get request in my component and i am showing the results in the html, everything is working but when i open the console i get the error. 'Cannot read property 'content' of undefined.

```
<div class="container myPadding">
<div class="form-row justify-content-center">
    <h1>Substances</h1>
</div>

<div class="form-row justify-content-center">
    <p class="alert alert-info">
        Total Substances registered: ({{ substanceList.totalElements }})
    </p>
</div>
<a>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Substance Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody *ngFor="let response of substanceList.content | slice:0:99">
            <tr>
                <td>{{response.neo4jId}}</td>
                <td>{{response.substanceName}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</a>
```

and ts file

```
export class SubstancesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
substanceList: any;
subscription: Subscription;

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private drugService: DrugsService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.getAllSubstances();
}

getAllSubstances() {
 this.subscription = this.drugService.getSubstances().subscribe(response => {
  this.substanceList = response;
  console.log(this.substanceList);
})
}

ngOnDestroy() {
 this.subscription.unsubscribe();
 }

}
```

and this is the function in my service

```
    getSubstances(): any {
    return this.http.get(environment.substancesUrl);
}
```

The result in the browser is the one i want to have but this error appears in the console, i would like to understand why this error occurs and how i can solve this.

Comment: Someone mentioned in.comments here for a similar message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45808908/typeerror-cannot-read-property-content-of-undefined " it was related to a spelling error of a file in an import" You would have to screenshot the whole message or copy/paste it somehow to be more certain.

Comment: content is property of your response?Are you using an *ngFor to presents the data on your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly access the elements of an object in the HTML page.

Please do the following changes:

```
  <tbody *ngFor="let response of substanceList && substanceList.content | slice:0:99">
```

OR

```
  <tbody *ngFor="let response of substanceList?.content | slice:0:99">
```

Comment: @TsolakidisKonstantinos Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add `?`s in front of all your object properties, e.g. `{{ substanceList?.totalElements }}` which prevents issues associated with trying to find the key `totalElements` on an object which is still being returned by the get request.

You will also likely want to add the async pipe to any variables which are populated as a result of an asynchronous call to ensure the data is only rendered to the screen once it is available (and does not briefly display `undefined` for example), e.g. `{{ substanceList?.totalElements | async }}`

Comment: i am doing an async call in my ts file because i subscribe, so the async PIPE in html is not needed, the ? is doing the job. That probably means, dont care about the type.